# How to prevent this error returning in a GUI Java Calculator?

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

I have built the following java calculator and it runs well with the exception of one function.  To illustrate the issue with my calculator, it is best to use an example. Once the Gui has been created from the code below, it is best to run the following inputs 9 + 6 and then type 3. the result will be 15.03. I am struggling to get the calculator to reset such that when a new integer is input following a result, the calculator simply inputs the new integer without repeating the display. would appreciate any help with this

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleCalculator extends JFrame {
private JButton b1;
private JButton b2;
private JButton b3;
private JButton b4;
private JButton b5;
private JButton b6;
private JButton b7;
private JButton b8;
private JButton b9;
private JButton b0;
private JButton be;
private JButton ba;
private JButton bs;
private JButton bm;
private JButton bd;
private JButton beq;
private JButton bce;
private JButton bdo;
private double TEMP;
private double SolveTEMP;
private JTextArea jtfResult;

Boolean addBool = false;
Boolean subBool = false;
Boolean divBool = false;
Boolean mulBool = false;

String display = "";

public SimpleCalculator() {
    this.setTitle("Simple Calculator");

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
    p1.add(b7 = new JButton("7"));
    p1.add(b8 = new JButton("8"));
    p1.add(b9 = new JButton("9"));
    p1.add(ba = new JButton("+"));
    p1.add(b4 = new JButton("4"));
    p1.add(b5 = new JButton("5"));
    p1.add(b6 = new JButton("6"));
    p1.add(bs = new JButton("-"));
    p1.add(b1 = new JButton("1"));
    p1.add(b2 = new JButton("2"));
    p1.add(b3 = new JButton("3"));
    p1.add(bm = new JButton("*"));
    p1.add(b0 = new JButton("0"));
    p1.add(bdo = new JButton("."));
    p1.add(bce = new JButton("CE"));
    p1.add(bd = new JButton("/"));

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p2.add(jtfResult = new JTextArea(10, 20));
    jtfResult.setEditable(false);

    /*JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    p3.add(ba = new JButton("+"));
    p3.add(bs = new JButton("-"));
    p3.add(bm = new JButton("*"));
    p3.add(bd = new JButton("/")); */

    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
    p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    p4.add(beq = new JButton("="));

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));
    p.add(p2);
    p.add(p1);
    //p.add(p3);
    p.add(p4);

    add(p);

    b1.addActionListener(new ListenToOne());
    b2.addActionListener(new ListenToTwo());
    b3.addActionListener(new ListenToThree());
    b4.addActionListener(new ListenToFour());
    b5.addActionListener(new ListenToFive());
    b6.addActionListener(new ListenToSix());
    b7.addActionListener(new ListenToSeven());
    b8.addActionListener(new ListenToEight());
    b9.addActionListener(new ListenToNine());
    b0.addActionListener(new ListenToZero());
    bdo.addActionListener(new ListenToDot());

    ba.addActionListener(new ListenToAdd());
    bs.addActionListener(new ListenToSubtract());
    bm.addActionListener(new ListenToMultiply());
    bd.addActionListener(new ListenToDivide());
    beq.addActionListener(new ListenToEqual());
    bce.addActionListener(new ListenToClear());

} 

class ListenToClear implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText("");
        addBool = false;
        subBool = false;
        mulBool = false;
        divBool = false;

        TEMP = 0;
        SolveTEMP = 0;
    }
}

class ListenToOne implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "1");
    }
}

class ListenToTwo implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "2");
    }
}

class ListenToThree implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "3");
    }
}

class ListenToFour implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "4");
    }
}

class ListenToFive implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "5");
    }
}

class ListenToSix implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "6");
    }
}

class ListenToSeven implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "7");
    }
}

class ListenToEight implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "8");
    }
}

class ListenToNine implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "9");
    }
}

class ListenToZero implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + "0");
    }
}

class ListenToDot implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        display = jtfResult.getText();
        jtfResult.setText(display + ".");
    }
}

class ListenToAdd implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
        jtfResult.setText("");
        addBool = true;
    }
}

class ListenToSubtract implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
        jtfResult.setText("");
        subBool = true;
    }
}

class ListenToMultiply implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
        jtfResult.setText("");
        mulBool = true;
    }
}

class ListenToDivide implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
        jtfResult.setText("");
        divBool = true;
    }
}

class ListenToEqual implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        SolveTEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
        if (addBool == true)
            SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP + TEMP;
        else if ( subBool == true)
            SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP - TEMP;
        else if ( mulBool == true)
            SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP * TEMP;
        else if ( divBool == true)
                        SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP / TEMP;
        jtfResult.setText(Double.toString(SolveTEMP));

        addBool = false;
        subBool = false;
        mulBool = false;
        divBool = false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleCalculator calc = new SimpleCalculator();
    calc.pack();
    calc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    calc.setVisible(true); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I made some modification to your code that I judge are better, I replaced all your ListenToOne, ListenToTwo, ... by one listener ListenToNumbers.

There's a mistake in your calculations, 10-5 print -5, and 10/5 print 0.5.

I solved your main issue by adding a boolean that will be set when we hit the equal button.

The final code

```
public class App extends JFrame {
    //...

    Boolean addBool = false;
    Boolean subBool = false;
    Boolean divBool = false;
    Boolean mulBool = false;

    boolean clean = false;

    String display = "";

    public SimpleCalculator () {
        // ...

        b1.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        b2.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        b3.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        b4.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        b5.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        b6.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        b7.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        b8.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        b9.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        b0.addActionListener(new ListenToNumbers());
        bdo.addActionListener(new ListenToDot());

        //....

    } 

    class ListenToNumbers implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             String digit = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
             display = jtfResult.getText();
             if (clean) {
                display = "";
                clean = false;
             }

             jtfResult.setText(display + digit);
        }
    }

    // ...

    class ListenToEqual implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            SolveTEMP = Double.parseDouble(jtfResult.getText());
            if (addBool == true)
                SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP + TEMP;
            else if ( subBool == true)
                SolveTEMP =  TEMP - SolveTEMP;
            else if ( mulBool == true)
                SolveTEMP = SolveTEMP * TEMP;
            else if ( divBool == true)
                 SolveTEMP = TEMP / SolveTEMP;
            jtfResult.setText(Double.toString(SolveTEMP));

            addBool = false;
            subBool = false;
            mulBool = false;
            divBool = false;
            clean = true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // code ... 
    }
}
```